# App not showing in Playstore for some model, but shows for other models that belongs to the same version

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, android-security, unity-game-engine

I have developed a game using Unity 4.

My game does not show in Play Store for Galaxy s7, s7 Edge, and Note 5 when I sort through the game category. I can find it through search, but when I try to download,  it says that it is not compatible. However, I was able to download in a different Galaxy S7. S7 comes with Android 6, so it is not an OS difference.

What should I be focusing on to find the cause of this issue?

Update: My coworker is going through multiple electronics stores and trying to download the app. Currently found one s6 that works and s6 that doesn't work. Unfortunately, the one that doesn't work is android 5.1.1 while s6 that does work is 6.0.1, so it's not a fair comparison atm. One thing interesting though is that I had gotten a message from Google saying that I have an unproper use of WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. And the two have different security versions. The one that works has "MDF v2.0 Release 6" and "VPN v1.4 Release 6.1" while the one that doesn't work has "MDF v2.0 Release 3" and "VPN v1.4 Release 5.2". Trying to figure out if that's the issue or not

Update2: Found one that is 6.0.1 that cannot download the app. I compared against Android 6's that work and doesn't work, and Android 5's that work and doesn't work. In both cases, the only things I can find that are different between those two were the "Security software version" and "Android security patch level"

Update3:
The devices that could not download the app were phones in the electronics stores, and they had CSC code of PAP, a CSC country code of HU, and no mobile operator. Googling tells me that PAP is used for Demo versions, which is obviously very likely the reason. Now, I need to find what in the demo version made it not be downloaded to confirm that it's specific to demo versions.

So, first I checked with region-specific publishing because it seemed like demo versions did not have a particular region. Turns out that two of my other apps that are set as global cannot be downloaded. I checked both my US google account and KR google account from my personal phone and both work fine with those apps. Even one another app that is set as Korea cannot be downloaded. Additionally, I was able to download one of my apps that is set as Korea only. Clearly, it seems unlikely it's related to region.

Comment: If you come up with the solution to this could you relay the information back to us? This is a pretty interesting case... I cant seem to find much about this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can think of is that the phones have custom ROM's installed. If the web-based version of Google Play Store shows it as incompatible as well though, you can click the little + next to it and it will show you what the problem is. Sorry but it's something you might have to take to the play store itself and ask for support.

Comment: Where do I ask for support? I can't find a support link

Comment: Look through the Throubleshoot section: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=15868